# Questions About UWP Permission Request Dialog UI

Tags: webview, uwp, accessibility

I have a UWP app with a WebView that may browse to webpages that request special permissions like the microphone, camera, or geolocation. For instance, I login to web.skype.com, it will request microphone and camera access. I added these capabilities to the appxmanifest so that it Windows prompts for permission. The problem with this is that I have no control over the UI of the popup that is displayed. My users may have special access needs (e.g. using an eye tracker) and I want to ensure they do not get stuck if one of these dialogs appears.

1) Is there any event or notification that Windows is about to show the dialog? I thought WebView.PermissionRequested was supposed to do this, but I am seeing that it is not invoked when I go to web.skype.com for microphone/camera permission, nor for weather.com for geolocation permission. Is there a different event at the app level that I can use for this? That way I can at least warn the user that a non-accessible dialog is about to appear so that they can prepare for it (e.g. ask for help).

Edit: For instance, app.xaml.cs has some virtual methods like OnFileOpenPickerActivated. I need something like OnPermissionRequested.

2) Is it possible to customize this UI in any way? Preferably I could replace the whole thing with my view. Next best would be to change the text to something like "Let web.skype.com access your microphone?" rather than "Let  access your microphone?"

Comment: The reason why these cannot be customized is that you could hide the actual request behind a random question.

Comment: @NielsNet yea, that makes sense, but I thought there might be some things that can be adjusted (e.g. button size, additional text).

Comment: As far as I found out yet there is no option. But maybe someone else found something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question was answered in the [msdn forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/e20896fc-5aeb-4338-9c99-4a949825f94c/questions-about-uwp-permission-request-dialog-ui?forum=wpdevelop), quoted here:

> Hi J.Nelson Tdx
>
> > Is there any event or notification that Windows is about to show the dialog?

The dialog will appear only when you need to use the related APIs.  There is no such event that could will be fired before the permission dialog shows. You could submit a feature request in the User Voice.

> > Is it possible to customize this UI in any way?

Currently, it is not possible to customize the Warning Alert. This is by design.

Best regards,

Roy

Comment: You should mark this as response. And maybe add a link to uservoice if you requested the dearure there so people can vote aswell and see the progress in future.